# How to get a list of the words inside a dictionary list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, format, jupyter

I have the following list:

> [('economy', 10160),
> ('to', 8407),
> ('the', 6617),
> ('in', 6378),
> ('Economy', 4060),
> ('of', 3846),
> ('for', 3713),
> ('on', 3351),
> ('a', 2189),
> ('as', 2070),
> ('and', 2023),
> ('is', 1677),
> ('economic', 1638),
> ('US', 1328),
> ('says', 1176),
> ('economy,', 1167),
> ('global', 1128),
> ('growth', 1084),
> ('at', 1007),
> ('The', 973),
> ('by', 878),
> ('-', 863),
> ('Economic', 849),
> ('will', 828),
> ('with', 715),
> ('be', 694),
> ('but', 686),
> ('economy:', 663),
> ('about', 648),
> ('boost', 641),
> ('Is', 635),
> ('could', 574),
> ('not', 554),
> ('Global', 551),
> ("China's", 550),
> ('UK', 502),
> ('from', 492),
> ('new', 491),
> ('than', 490),
> ('up', 487),
> ('more', 486),
> ('Brexit', 473),
> ('over', 472),
> ('China', 470),
> ('\x9d\x9d\x9d', 447),
> ('U.S.', 442),
> ('rate', 428),
> ('grow', 427),
> ('are', 419),
> ('may', 388),
> ('2016', 381),
> ('To', 376),
> ('Economy,', 371),
> ('oil', 363),
> ('has', 348),
> ('In', 344),
> ('can', 343),
> ('Fed', 338),
> ('New', 335),
> ('Chinese', 330),
> ('GDP', 323),
> ('jobs', 318),
> ('world', 311),
> ('grows', 310),
> ('its', 308),
> ('Growth', 300),
> ('still', 297),
> ('into', 296),
> ('would', 296),
> ('Economy:', 293),
> ('growing', 291),
> ('market', 289),
> ('percent', 286),
> ('an', 286),
> ('About', 285),
> ('Will', 274),
> ('despite', 272),
> ('A', 271),
> ('warns', 268),
> ('help', 265),
> ('grew', 263),
> ('...The', 262),
> ('EU', 261),
> ('Says', 261),
> ('Bank', 256),
> ('minister', 255),
> ('after', 251),
> ('year', 244),
> ('first', 243),
> ('2016:', 243),
> ('hit', 236),
> ('that', 232),
> ('good', 229),
> ('pct', 223),
> ('More', 222),
> ('shows', 220),
> ('have', 219),
> ('amid', 214),
> ('it', 213),
> ('economyThe', 211),
> ('sees', 207)]

Now I need to get a list of just the words without their count value, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is called `word_counts`

```py
[pair[0] for pair in word_counts]
```